# Problemas con select en angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Tengo esta página **html**

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content black-text">  
             <h6><strong>Server</strong></h6>             
             <select id="serverSelectServer" [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado" (change)="onSelectServer()">
               <option value="All">All servers</option>
               <option *ngFor="let xserver of serversCodifiers" value="{{ xserver.name }}">{{ xserver.name }}</option>
             </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y este es el **component.ts**

```
onSelectServer(){
console.log("changed");
}
```

Mi problema es que necesito obtener el valor de lo que se selecciona en el select , pero por alguna extraña razón el evento no se me ejecuta . Agradecería mucho su ayuda , muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En el `select` tendras que poner:

```
[(ngModel)]="**variable**"
```

Y en el `controller` tendrás que declarar la **variable**. Esta **variable** obtendrá el valor del `value` de la opción del `select`.

Espero que sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de obtener el valor en el momento que se realiza el cambio es utilizar el decorador `Output()` del ngModel, `(ngModelChange)` de la siguiente forma en el template (html):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado" (ngModelChange)="onSelectServer($event)">
```

y puedes capturar el cambio en el componente así:

```
onSelectServer(opcion) {
   console.log(opcion);
   //opcion es el valor emitido por el select en el evento de cambio(change)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar el valor de la opcion seleccionada deberias usar `onSelectionChange` en lugar de `change` y el parametro `$event` para capturar su valor, en tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content black-text">
        <h6><strong>Server</strong></h6>
        <select id="serverSelectServer" [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectServer($event)">
          <option value="All">All servers</option>
          <option *ngFor="let xserver of serversCodifiers" value="{{ xserver.name }}">{{ xserver.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y en la logica de tu componente

```
onSelectServer(opcion) {
    if (opcion.isUserInput) {
      console.log(opcion.value);
    }
}
```